# how to run commands in command prompt in window

Tags: magento-2.1

I am getting error in command line in window. "command is not recognized as an internal and external command. operable program or batch file". this error occurs when i run any command.

Comment: Check my answer and @parth's answer. Let me know if it didnt work.

Answer (score 3):

You can run php pages using php.exe create some php file with php code and in the cmd write:

> [PATH to php.ext]\php.exe [path_to_file]\file.php

you can also add path of php.exe in system PATH environment variable so you can use PHP as command from any directory in windows.

Example Case:

1. My XAMPP is installed on D:\php\ and php.exe resides in D:\php\php and Magento folder is here D:\php\htdocs\MG\m212 ( http://localhost/MG/m212/)
2. Go on to D drive.
3. D:\php\php>php D:\php\htdocs\MG\m212\bin\magento indexer:reindex

On XAMPP:

```
 Installed Xampp_root/php>php   'Path_to_project'
```

On WAMPP: The PHP CLI as its called ( php for the Command Line Interface ) is called php.exe It lives in c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.x.y\php.exe
( where x and y are the version numbers of php that you have installed )

Answer (score 0):

You have to go to the php folder where xampp is installed and then run the commands by passing the full path to

> magento\bin

For example, I have php folder under F: drive. So, I will first go to F:/xampp/php and then will run the commands. e.g.

> php F:\xampp\htdocs\magento-2\bin\magento setup:upgrade

Answer (score 0):

Open **CLI** from **Xampp** and go inside project.
Assumed your project and **xampp** on `D:` Drive:

Navigate inside project like: cd `D:\xampp\htdocs\Magento2`

CLI Path will be like: `D:\xampp\htdocs\Magento2`
`php bin\magento setup:upgrade`